# Batch set a var not always working in loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, set

Sometimes my call :GetTime procedure is working sometimes not. 
Sometimes my archives get named just .rar instead of for example 23.05.2017_22-02-07.rar

why does this happen? Most of the time it works fine....

```
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"%MD5% default_main_GlobalData.CSF"`) do set StartMD5=%%a
    for %%a in (%StartMD5%) do set StartMD5=%StartMD5:~0,32%
    :Proc1
    if exist del "%Workdir%\SniperGhostWarrior3_Savegames\Hidden\.rar"
    if exist del "%Workdir%\SniperGhostWarrior3_Savegames\Profile\.rar"
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"%MD5% default_main_GlobalData.CSF"`) do set CurrentMD5=%%a
    for %%a in (%CurrentMD5%) do set CurrentMD5=%CurrentMD5:~0,32%
    if not "%CurrentMD5%" == "%StartMD5%" (
    call :GetTime
    %Winrar% a -inul "%Workdir%\SniperGhostWarrior3_Savegames\Hidden\Temp.rar" "C:\Users\Administrator\Saved Games\Sniper Ghost Warrior 3\"
    %Winrar% a -inul "%Workdir%\SniperGhostWarrior3_Savegames\Profile\Temp.rar" "D:\Spiele\Sniper Ghost Warrior 3\win_x64\Profile"
    ren "%Workdir%\SniperGhostWarrior3_Savegames\Hidden\Temp.rar" "%CurrentTime%.rar" >nul 2>&1
    ren "%Workdir%\SniperGhostWarrior3_Savegames\Profile\Temp.rar" "%CurrentTime%.rar" >nul 2>&1
    set "StartMD5=%CurrentMD5%"
    echo Game Saved. Backup created. %CurrentTime%
    )
    goto :Proc1
    :GetTime
    set "CurrentTime=%date%_%time:~0,-3%"
    set word=-
    call set CurrentTime=%%CurrentTime::=%word%%%
    goto :eof
```

Comment: What are the `for %%a` loops for? You never use its variable `%%a` in the body... And `if exist del` is wrong syntax -- see `if /?`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see endless articles about `delayedexpansion`. You are setting `currenttime` in a subroutine, but the `currenttime` used in the code block is the value of `currenttime` at the time the `for` is encountered, not as changed by the subroutine.

Easiest way : move `call :gettime` to before the `if not "%CurrentMD5%" ==...`

Comment: I was too lazy my bad. 
Thanky you, its working fine now i should have known this.

Answer (score 1):

In a loop, the variables take their values at the end of loop..
If you want to use them Inside your loop, put this line in the top of your batch :

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

and inside your loop, call the variable like that :

```
!var!
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you. But setlocal would cause recursive depth error.